# How to set background image in Angular 4

Tags: html, css, angular

## Code

```html
<div class="wrapper wrapper-full-page">
  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="page-header login-page header-filter" filter-color="black"
         style="background-image: url('./assets/img/fundo.jpg'); background-size: cover; background- 
         position: top center;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## What I want to achieve

I'm trying to set a background image in my login page. In chrome it's working perfectly but in firefox the image is cropped. How can i fix this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtfPb.png)

Comment: Can you add a screenshot what happens or to create a stackblitz and please add your css style for these divs ?

Comment: I added a screenshot to show what happens and all my style for that divs it's in that html

Comment: First , make sure tht you have this code in polyfills.ts:

import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
(window as any).global = window;

Comment: Yeah, i have this code